# basic REST in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, rest

What's the most basic and headache-free rest implementation I can have in Angular?

I've tired this :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  restCall(term:string, id:string) {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let apiURL = `http://localhost:3000/todos$/{term}/${id}`;
      this.http.get(apiURL)
        .toPromise()
        .then(
          res => { // Success
            this.results = res.json().results;
            resolve();
          },
          msg => { // Error
            reject(msg);
          }
        );
    });
    return promise;
  }
}
```

The back is setrp like this : localhost:3000/todos
With possible calls : get , get/id, post, put/id, delete/id

I figure with this url `http://localhost:3000/todos/${term}/${id}` I have all my rest call refactored into one method.

where all my joy stops is here :

[image]
[image]

Am I close or going the wrong way entirely?

Comment: You are using TypeScript, you have to actually declare type members there. Neither `http` nor `results` are defined, so of course you get those compiler errors. Note that you need to *inject* `Http` via dependency injection in order to get a http object. Check out the Angular manual.

Comment: ok thanks. the docs are pretty poor on this.

Comment: The [guide on the HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) is actually pretty thorough…

Comment: sorry I hadn't found that one. dunno why

Comment: @poke I'm having big problems with it now the part were it says `interface ItemsResponse` where is that supposed to go? my IDE says unexpected token. why do docs omit context?

Comment: this guy explains it in a way were you can actually succeed : https://www.barbarianmeetscoding.com/blog/2016/04/02/getting-started-with-angular-2-step-by-step-6-consuming-real-data-with-http/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In angular 2 or higher I add all my http calls inside a service. But to fix your errors you should try this.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  results: any;

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  restCall(term:string, id:string) {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let apiURL = `http://localhost:3000/todos$/{term}/${id}`;
      this.http.get(apiURL)
        .toPromise()
        .then(
          res => { // Success
            this.results = res.json().results;
            resolve();
          },
          msg => { // Error
            reject(msg);
          }
        );
    });
    return promise;
  }
}
```

I imported the Http service and declare it inside constructor.
results variable is not a local variable so you should declare it before the constructor.